# Really old questions on the "Close Votes Review", with no votes

Tags: support

Just now as I opened the Close Votes review tab, there were some really old  questions:

- [Is there a term for music composed of everyday sounds?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/24201/is-there-a-term-for-music-composed-of-everyday-sounds)
- [Is there a single command for vertical padding in LilyPond \markup?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/23250/is-there-a-single-command-for-vertical-padding-in-lilypond-markup)

I couldn't really see any reason to vote to close them, and when I clicked to see what some other person had used a reason to close, there were no votes.

Both of these questions haven't been active for years. Is this some kind of bug, or did just someone voted to close them and then retracted their vote?

Comment: It's possible they were flagged by someone without the vote  to close privilege. I'm pretty sure when flagged like that is goes to our queue without any votes on it.

Comment: I've seen lots of posts in the closure review queue with no recorded close votes, and as Dom says, I think that's due to flags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reviewing the questions posted, they were flagged as off-topic by a user without the privilege to vote to close. This puts it in the queue, but without any votes to close on it.

In general just handle it as you would any other question in the queue as voting to leave open will get it out of the queue.